# New to coding and using meteor. Deployment issue

Tags: meteor, deployment, iron-router

I have created a very simple app to start out my learning process. I used the meteor deployment steps and I receive this error on the page.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
 this.render('Home', {
   data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
 });
});
```

I have searched online about it and unfortunately I do not have the router knowledge to understand many of the answers. I will put my routing code here:

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate:'layout'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
 this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/red', function () {
 this.render('red');
});

Router.route('/yellow', function () {
 this.render('yellow');
});

Router.route('/green', function () {
 this.render('green');
});

Router.route('/home', function () {
 this.render('home');
});
```

It routes fine in the localhost.  If anyone could help me or poit me in the correct direction that would really help. I am extremely new to this (started last week) so please understand that. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to indicate the actual error?

Comment: Did you forget to write the "error" you receive on running this? Just asking, which path do you use to render "home" template in your app, is it just ` / ` or `/home`. I see you are using both these path to render same page.

Comment: The "error" is Router.route('/', function () {
 this.render('Home', {
   data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
 });
}); Is what the screen shows rather than the app. I am using the '/' for home I just added the last one to see if that would make it work.

Comment: maybe error is the incorrect word.  The app is just not functioning and the scree just says Iron Router and has what I linked in my reply.

Comment: @Greenhorn /home is it I have since removed the other. Still having the same issue =(

Comment: Thank you both very much for your responses. I have figured out the issue and fixed it and it is now working properly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually from the demo js that existed in the meteor template. Once I deleted the code from that js it works great!